# Primefaces ScrollPanel with toggleable Fieldset

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Primefaces scrollpanel that has a datatable along with a Primefaces expandable Fieldset which is collapsed by default. My scrollpanel has fixed height. now the issue is whenever I Expand the Primefaces Fieldset,some of the Portion of Datatable that is present within the Scrollpanel gets cut off  as the space is taken up by the expanded fieldset.
Can anyone tell me how can I get over this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure there is an issue.  The scroll panel stays a specific size and has scrollbars that the user will use to navigate items within that are bigger than the scrollpanel itself.  This is exactly as a scrollpanel should work.

Comment: @maple_shaft yes you are right but how do i make it work with a toggelable fieldset of Primefaces ? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fieldset.jsf  what I want to do is resize height of the scrollpanel automatically whenever the fieldset is Expanded. which is not happening in current situation